# Method implied interpretation of parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Running the following from a WinForms

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("A", "B");
```

The first paramter "A" is the body and "B" appears as the title.

`Show` is an overloaded method - VS IDE shows 21 overloads but the option with 2 parameters is

```
Show(IWin32Window owner,string text)
```

I don't understand how `IWin32Window owner` relates to "A" above ... or is there an implicit interpretation of the parameters supplied?

Comment: Overloads can have the same number of arguments with different argument types. See @nemesv's answer.

Comment: F12 on the `.Show` call will take you straight to the correct overload being used, just for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a string, string [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s.aspx):

```
public static DialogResult Show(
    string text,
    string caption
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case [MessageBox.Show Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20stz12s.aspx) is applied.